# Xcode 4 fonts default to Helvetica

Tags: xcode, fonts

I have Xcode 4 running on a brand-new MacBook Pro. My problem is this: when choosing fonts from the Mac OS font picker, only a handful are displayed properly; the rest appear as Helvetica. I don't have this problem in any other applications, Apple or otherwise. Here are the fonts that are displayed correctly:

Arial, Arial Rounded, Baskerville, Cochin, Courier, Courier New, Futura, Georgia, Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Marker Felt, Palatino, Times New Roman, Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Zapfino

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making an iOS app and selecting font attributes for the app? If so, note that iOS doesn't have all the fonts that OSX has.

Comment: Well, at least it's not Comic Sans.

Comment: Yes, that is fortunate. Thank you DA, problem (er, non-problem) solved!

Answer (score 0):

Mine is xcode 4.2 and every thing works fine. but if it doesn't work for you the easy way is to call the font from your code.

```
//am using a font called "Ethiopic WashRa Bold
//Copy it to your resource folder and that is it
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ethiopic WashRa Bold" size:14];
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Title"];

cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ethiopic WashRa Bold" size:10];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Group"];
```

If your question is different please let me know so that i can understand better.